Linear Approximation of Integral of Argument Function
I am interested in the following integral, where $A$ is a complex number (one may assume $|A| \approx 1$):
$$
I(A) = \int_0^1{arg(1+tA)dt}
$$
The closed-form to this integral is somewhat complicated, but I am actually interested in the best linear function $f(A) = c_0+c_1 \cdot A + c_2\cdot \overline{A}$ that approximates $I(A)$ in the best way (least squares? not a must but it should be reasonable).
This is not an obvious question. For instance, the line $(0,arg(1))\rightarrow(1,arg(A))$ is not a good approximation, as it ignores $|A|$ (which modules the speed in which the argument changes along the line). Maybe the linear approximation around $t=0.5$ is helpful? Note that while $arg(1+t*A)$ might not be well defined (when $A=-1$), the integral always is.
